# Загрузка картинки на сервер

Tags: php

Нигде не могу найти примера загрузки картинки на сервер не из формы, а из POST запроса. Помогите переделать этот пример с php.net:

```
<?php
// В PHP 4.1.0 и более ранних версиях следует использовать $HTTP_POST_FILES
// вместо $_FILES.

$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Файл корректен и был успешно загружен.\n";
} else {
    echo "Возможная атака с помощью файловой загрузки!\n";
}

echo 'Некоторая отладочная информация:';
print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Форма это набор именованных данных, POST/GET/PUT/DELETE/REQUEST - методы передачи данных. Передача в основном идет через тело запроса (ваш POST), или параметры запроса (GET - через него файл не получиться передать). Форма лишь помогает Вам удобно загрузить файл через POST метод на сервер. Вам требуется обязательно почитать про [передачу параметров извне](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.external.php)

Приведенный пример загрузки файла корректный. Передача файла из формы/запроса будет осуществляться методом POST. В данном примере есть свои проблемы, например нет функции is_uploaded_file, которая проверяет что файл загружен или нет проверки, что загружается именно картинка, в коде ниже реализовал данную проверку.

```
<?php

$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']))  
{
     echo "Загрузка файла на сервер не удалась";
     die(); //or throw exception...
} 

//Проверка что это картинка

if (!getimagesize($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"])) {
     echo "Это не картинка...";
     die(); //or throw exception...
}

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Файл корректен и был успешно загружен.\n";
} else {
    echo "Возможная атака с помощью файловой загрузки!\n";
}

?>
```

Чтобы передать данные скрипту нужно создать форму на HTML с enctype="multipart/form-data"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="userfile" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Если вы хотите отправлять данные без браузера, можете воспользоваться CURL. Запуск POST запроса из командной строки для передачи файла выглядит вот так:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" 
-F "data=@test.mp3" http://myserver/upload
```

Comment: Всегда пишет ошибку: Возможная атака с помощью файловой загрузки!\n Путь до папки с картинками такой: /s92640jz.bget.ru/public_html/engine/

Comment: Значит файл не может быть перемещен в ту папку, выставите в папке в которую перемещаете данные права 777 (chmod), в консоли это делается с помощью chmod 777 folder_name или из хостинг панели тоже можно установить подобные разрешения.

Comment: Права есть уже проверял

Comment: а почему такое название папки engine ? не пробовали адекватное название сделать, типа imgs и тд?? мне кажется, такое имя папки определяется как служебное, используемой БЕГЕТом. у вас же там ВП? зачем огород городите, среди плагинов для ВП миллиард решений для загрузки файлов, картинок-мартинок и тд!! да и без плагинов решений хватает. осень на дворе, велосипеды пора консервировать!